# Docker: how to force graylog web interface over https?

Tags: ssl, docker, https, graylog2

I'm currently struggling to get graylog working over https in a docker environment. I'm using the jwilder/nginx-proxy and I have the certificates in place.
When I run:

```
docker run --name=graylog-prod --link mongo-prod:mongo --link elastic-prod:elasticsearch -e VIRTUAL_PORT=9000 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=test.myserver.com -e GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI="http://test.myserver.com/api" -e GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper -e GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918 -d graylog2/server
```

I get the following error:

> We are experiencing problems connecting to the Graylog server running
>   on http://test.myserver.com:9000/api. Please verify that the server is
>   healthy and working correctly.
>
> You will be automatically redirected to the previous page once we can
>   connect to the server.
>
> This is the last response we received from the server:
>
> Error message
>       Bad request Original Request
>       GET http://test.myserver.com/api/system/sessions Status code
>       undefined Full error message
>       Error: Request has been terminated
>       Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.

When I go to the URL in the message, I get a reply: {"session_id":null,"username":null,"is_valid":false}
This is the same reply I get when running Graylog without https.

In the docker log file from the graylog is nothing mentioned.
docker ps:

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND
>   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
>                                     NAMES 56c9b3b4fc74        graylog2/server                          "/docker-entrypoint.s"   5
>   minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        9000/tcp,  12900/tcp
>   graylog-prod

When running docker with the option -p 9000:9000 all is working fine without https, but as soon as I force it to go over https I get this error.

Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI="https://test.myserver.com/api" ?